# T-SQL Query for value apportioning

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a requirement in which I need to evenly apportion a value across multiple records. Below is how my data looks like

```
Relationship Table
-------------------------------------------------------
CategoryID         SubCategoryID
-------------------------------------------------------
101                1
101                2
101                3
102                4
102                5      

Table 1
-------------------------------------------------------
BatchLine ID       CategoryID       Amount
-------------------------------------------------------
1                  101              10
2                  102              100
3                  101              100

Table 2
-------------------------------------------------------------------
LineID    BatchLineID    CategoryID    SubCategoryID    LineValue
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1         1              101           1                3.33
2         1              101           2                3.33
3         1              101           3                3.33  
4         2              102           4                66.66
5         2              102           5                33.33
6         3              101           1                33.33
7         3              101           2                33.33
8         3              101           3                33.33
```

In 'Table 2' the 'LineValue' is the resultant of calculations made on the 'Amount' field from 'Table 1' and the final value is then rounded to two decimal points. In some cases the rounding process causes some difference in value with the 'Amount' field in 'Table 1'.

```
Difference
------------------------------------------------------------------
BatchLineID    CategoryID    Amount    SumofLineValue  
------------------------------------------------------------------
1              101           10        9.99  
2              102           100       99.99 
3              101           100       99.99
```

In order to match the 'Amount' value from 'Table 1' we need to add '0.01' to each 'LineID' with in the CategoryID group till the sum of 'LineValue' equals it.

There is one more condition, in the case of 'CategoryID' 101 there are two sets of data in 'Table 2'. We add '0.01' to LineID 1 this will make the sum to match the 'Amount' field from 'Table 1'. When we need to apportion the second set need to start with the 'Line ID' of  7 instead of 6. Below is my expected out data.

```
Expected Output
-------------------------------------------------------------------
LineID    BatchLineID    CategoryID    SubCategoryID    LineValue
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1         1              101           1                3.33 + 0.01
2         1              101           2                3.33
3         1              101           3                3.33  
4         2              102           4                66.66 + 0.01
5         2              102           5                33.33
6         3              101           1                33.33
7         3              101           2                33.33 + 0.01
8         3              101           3                33.33
```

Comment: Is LineValue defined as decimal(x,2)?

Comment: @McNets Yes, It is defined as Decimal(X,2)

Comment: Is there a max of 3 lines by Batch?

Comment: @McNets No number of lines in a Batch is not limited to 3.

Comment: Then you can get 2 lines for the first batch and 4 lines for the second within the same category?

Comment: I mean, Cat:101, 3 categories, 1st: 3 lines, 2nd: 3 lines, 3rd: 2 lines. Which must be updated for the 3rd batch?

Comment: For the 3rd batch 'SubCategoryID' 2 needs to be added with '0.01' since for the first 'CategoryID' group batch we have already added '0.01' to the 'SubCategoryID' 1.

Answer (score 0):

As far as there isn't nothing that flags which records must be updated, this solution updates the first record of each group.

> ```
> with rn as 
> (
>     select t2.LineID, t1.BatchLineID, t1.CategoryID, t1.Amount, t2.SubCategoryID,
>            sum(t2.LineValue) over (partition by t2.BatchLineID, t2.CategoryID) as ActSum,
>            row_number() over (partition by t2.BatchLineID, t2.CategoryID order by SubCategoryID) as RNum 
>     from      t1
>     left join t2
>     on        t1.BatchLineID = t2.BatchLineID
>     and       t1.CategoryID = t2.CategoryID
> )
> update     t2
> set        LineValue = LineValue + (Amount - ActSum)
> from       t2 tt2
> inner join rn
> on         tt2.LineID = rn.LineID
> where      RNum = 1 
> and        Amount <> ActSum;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> select * from t2;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> LineID | BatchLineID | CategoryID | SubCategoryID | LineValue
> -----: | ----------: | ---------: | ------------: | :--------
>      1 |           1 |        101 |             1 | 3.34     
>      2 |           1 |        101 |             2 | 3.33     
>      3 |           1 |        101 |             3 | 3.33     
>      4 |           2 |        102 |             4 | 66.67    
>      5 |           2 |        102 |             5 | 33.33    
>      6 |           3 |        101 |             1 | 33.34    
>      7 |           3 |        101 |             2 | 33.33    
>      8 |           3 |        101 |             3 | 33.33
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=eb2e07be26218d98f698b6f461c35366)*

Comment: The requirement is to not add the same 'SubCategoryID' again. In the case of second group for 'CategoryID' 101 LineID 7 should be added with '0.01'. That is the real catch here.

Comment: Ok, let me think a solution for that

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the fiddle from McNets, you could use `dense_rank()` to determine which row should be updated:

```
with cte1 as (
    select t2.LineID, t1.BatchLineID, t1.CategoryID, t1.Amount, t2.SubCategoryID,
           sum(t2.LineValue) over (partition by t2.BatchLineID, t2.CategoryID) as ActSum,
           row_number() over (partition by t2.BatchLineID, t2.CategoryID order by SubCategoryID) as RNum,
           dense_rank() over (partition by t1.CategoryID order by t1.BatchLineID) as drank
    from      t1
    left join t2
    on        t1.BatchLineID = t2.BatchLineID
    and       t1.CategoryID = t2.CategoryID
)
select a.LineID, a.BatchLineID, a.CategoryID, a.SubCategoryID, case when drank = rnum then a.LineValue + (b.Amount - b.ActSum) else a.LineValue end as LineValue
from t2 a
left join cte1 b
  on a.LineID = b.LineID
```

Note that you could run in to problems where subsequent groups doesn't have enough rows and therefore no row is updated.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Josh. But not necessarily we need to add for the second line for the second instance and the third line in the third instance. It needs to be dynamic if we stopped apportioning at the second 'SubCategoryID' in the first group then we need to start apportioning at the third 'SubCategoryID' in the second group. And moreover we need to evenly add '0.01' across records instead of adding the difference to just one record.

Comment: Perhaps your question needs these details then?